# Ordered search results in Mongodb?

Tags: search, full-text-search, mongodb

Am doing a simple tag search using mongodb with data being stored in a list.

```
Entity A {_id:...,tags : ['a','b','f']}
Entity B {_id:...,tags : ['g','a','v']}
Entity C {_id:...,tags : ['a','c','e']}
Entity D {_id:...,tags : ['c','s','e']}
Entity E {_id:...,tags : ['a','c','s']}
```

Search String : 'a c s g'

Query being

```
db.collecction.find({tags:{$in:['a','c','s','g']}})
```

Expected Response would be Entity with most matching tags at top and rest thereafter.

Reponse:

```
1.Entity E - 3 tags matched
2.Entity D/C/B - 2 tags matched
3.Entity C/B/D - 2 tags matched
4.Entity B/D/C - 2 tags matched
5.Entity A - 1 tag matched
```

What would be the best way to achieve the same??

Answer (score 4):

You have to implement the ranking/sorting on the application level.
There is nothing in MongoDB that would help you here.

You may look into

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation

but I don't see how this could be used for your particular usecase.

Comment: Any application level implementation would very inefficient when mongodb returns 1000's of results. Isn't there some  server side custom JS implementation ? Can you point out something in this direction?

Comment: is correct here, there is no support for applying functions in the `sort()`. You effectively want a "best match" function to be applied.